# Can ASP.NET Routing be used to create "clean" URLs for .ashx (IHttpHander) handlers?

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler, asp.net-routing

I have some REST services using plain old `IHttpHandler`s.  I'd like to generate cleaner URLs, so that I don't have the .ashx in the path.  Is there a way to use ASP.NET routing to create routes that map to ashx handlers?  I've seen these types of routes previously:

```
// Route to an aspx page
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("route-name",
    "some/path/{arg}",
    "~/Pages/SomePage.aspx");

// Route for a WCF service
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/SomeService",
    new WebServiceHostFactory(),
    typeof(SomeService)));
```

Trying to use `RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute()` generates an error (that the handler does not derive from `Page`).  `System.Web.Routing.RouteBase` only seems to have 2 derived classes: `ServiceRoute` for services, and `DynamicDataRoute` for MVC.  I'm not sure what `MapPageRoute()` does (Reflector doesn't show the method body, it just shows "Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries").

I see that `RouteBase` is not sealed, and has a relatively simple interface:

```
public abstract RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext);

public abstract VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext,
    RouteValueDictionary values);
```

So perhaps I can make my own HttpHandlerRoute.  I'll give that a shot, but if anyone knows of an existing or built-in way of mapping routes to IHttpHandlers, that would be great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, I've been figuring this out since I originally asked the question, and I finally have a solution that does just what I want.  A bit of up front explanation is due, however.  IHttpHandler is a very basic interface:

```
bool IsReusable { get; }
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

There is no built in property for accessing the route data, and the route data also can't be found in the context or the request.  A `System.Web.UI.Page` object has a `RouteData` property , `ServiceRoute`s do all the work of interpreting your UriTemplates and passing the values to the correct method internally, and ASP.NET MVC provides its own way of accessing the route data.  Even if you had a `RouteBase` that (a) determined if the incoming url was a match for your route and (b) parsed the url to extract all of the individual values to be used from within your IHttpHandler, there's no easy way to pass that route data to your IHttpHandler.  If you want to keep your IHttpHandler "pure", so to speak, it takes responsibility for dealing with the url, and how to extract any values from it.  The RouteBase implementation in this case is only used to determine if your IHttpHandler should be used at all.

One problem remains, however.  Once the RouteBase determines that the incoming url is a match for your route, it passes off to an IRouteHandler, which creates the instances of the IHttpHandler you want to handle your request.  But, once you're in your IHttpHandler, the value of `context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath` is misleading.  It's the url that came from the client, minus the query string.  So it's not the path to your .ashx file.  And, any parts of your route that are constant (such as the name of the method) will be part of that execution file path value.  This can be a problem if you use UriTemplates within your IHttpHandler to determine which specific method within your IHttpHandler should handing the request.

Example:  If you had a .ashx handler at /myApp/services/myHelloWorldHandler.ashx
And you had this route that mapped to the handler: "services/hello/{name}"
And you navigated to this url, trying to call the `SayHello(string name)` method of your handler:
http://localhost/myApp/services/hello/SayHello/Sam

Then your `CurrentExecutionFilePath` would be: /myApp/services/hello/Sam.  It includes parts of the route url, which is a problem.  You want the execution file path to match your route url.  The below implementations of `RouteBase` and `IRouteHandler` deal with this problem.

Before I paste the 2 classes, here's a very simple usage example.  Note that these implementations of RouteBase and IRouteHandler will actually work for IHttpHandlers that don't even have a .ashx file, which is pretty convenient.

```
// A "headless" IHttpHandler route (no .ashx file required)
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new GenericHandlerRoute<HeadlessService>("services/headless"));
```

That will cause all incoming urls that match the "services/headless" route to be handed off to a new instance of the `HeadlessService` IHttpHandler (HeadlessService is just an example in this case.  It would be whatever IHttpHandler implementation you wanted to pass off to).

Ok, so here are the routing class implementations, comments and all:

```
/// <summary>
/// For info on subclassing RouteBase, check Pro Asp.NET MVC Framework, page 252.
/// Google books link: http://books.google.com/books?id=tD3FfFcnJxYC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=.net+RouteBase&source=bl&ots=IQhFwmGOVw&sig=0TgcFFgWyFRVpXgfGY1dIUc0VX4&hl=en&ei=z61UTMKwF4aWsgPHs7XbAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=.net%20RouteBase&f=false
/// 
/// It explains how the asp.net runtime will call GetRouteData() for every route in the route table.
/// GetRouteData() is used for inbound url matching, and should return null for a negative match (the current requests url doesn't match the route).
/// If it does match, it returns a RouteData object describing the handler that should be used for that request, along with any data values (stored in RouteData.Values) that
/// that handler might be interested in.
/// 
/// The book also explains that GetVirtualPath() (used for outbound url generation) is called for each route in the route table, but that is not my experience,
/// as mine used to simply throw a NotImplementedException, and that never caused a problem for me.  In my case, I don't need to do outbound url generation,
/// so I don't have to worry about it in any case.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class GenericHandlerRoute<T> : RouteBase where T : IHttpHandler, new()
{
    public string RouteUrl { get; set; }


    public GenericHandlerRoute(string routeUrl)
    {
        RouteUrl = routeUrl;
    }


    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // See if the current request matches this route's url
        string baseUrl = httpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;
        int ix = baseUrl.IndexOf(RouteUrl);
        if (ix == -1)
            // Doesn't match this route.  Returning null indicates to the asp.net runtime that this route doesn't apply for the current request.
            return null;

        baseUrl = baseUrl.Substring(0, ix + RouteUrl.Length);

        // This is kind of a hack.  There's no way to access the route data (or even the route url) from an IHttpHandler (which has a very basic interface).
        // We need to store the "base" url somewhere, including parts of the route url that are constant, like maybe the name of a method, etc.
        // For instance, if the route url "myService/myMethod/{myArg}", and the request url were "http://localhost/myApp/myService/myMethod/argValue",
        // the "current execution path" would include the "myServer/myMethod" as part of the url, which is incorrect (and it will prevent your UriTemplates from matching).
        // Since at this point in the exectuion, we know the route url, we can calculate the true base url (excluding all parts of the route url).
        // This means that any IHttpHandlers that use this routing mechanism will have to look for the "__baseUrl" item in the HttpContext.Current.Items bag.
        // TODO: Another way to solve this would be to create a subclass of IHttpHandler that has a BaseUrl property that can be set, and only let this route handler
        // work with instances of the subclass.  Perhaps I can just have RestHttpHandler have that property.  My reticence is that it would be nice to have a generic
        // route handler that works for any "plain ol" IHttpHandler (even though in this case, you have to use the "global" base url that's stored in HttpContext.Current.Items...)
        // Oh well.  At least this works for now.
        httpContext.Items["__baseUrl"] = baseUrl;

        GenericHandlerRouteHandler<T> routeHandler = new GenericHandlerRouteHandler<T>();
        RouteData rdata = new RouteData(this, routeHandler);

        return rdata;
    }


    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // This route entry doesn't generate outbound Urls.
        return null;
    }
}



public class GenericHandlerRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler where T : IHttpHandler, new()
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

I know this answer has been quite long winded, but it was not an easy problem to solve.  The core logic was easy enough, the trick was to somehow make your IHttpHandler aware of the "base url", so that it could properly determine what parts of the url belong to the route, and what parts are actual arguments for the service call.

These classes will be used in my upcoming C# REST library, [RestCake](http://rest.codeplex.com).  I hope that my path down the routing rabbit hole will help anyone else who decides to RouteBase, and do cool stuff with IHttpHandlers.

Answer (score 14):

I actually like Joel's solution better, as it doesn't require you to know the type of handler while you're trying to setup your routes. I'd upvote it, but alas, I haven't the reputation required.

I actually found a solution which I feel is better than both mentioned. The original source code I derived my example from can be found linked here http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/07/introducing-smartyroute-a-smarty-ier-way-to-do-routing-in-asp-net-applications.aspx.

This is less code, type agnostic, and fast.

```
public class HttpHandlerRoute : IRouteHandler {

  private String _VirtualPath = null;

  public HttpHandlerRoute(String virtualPath) {
    _VirtualPath = virtualPath;
  }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = (IHttpHandler)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_VirtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler));
    return httpHandler;
  }
}
```

And a rough example of use

```
String handlerPath = "~/UploadHandler.ashx";
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("files/upload", new HttpHandlerRoute(handlerPath)));
```

Comment: While you may not have to know the type of the IHttpHandler implementation, you do have to know the path to the ashx file.  My solution doesn't require an ashx file at all, and it's a compile time check.  Your solution will cause a runtime error if the setup is bad.  It's just as easy to refer to the type of a handler as it is to refer to the path of the ashx.  Safer too.  It is much easier to understand though, and that's nice.  Simple is good.  I'm gonna stick with mine just the same, because I like not having to have the ashx file.  I just create a plain class that implements IHttpHandler.

Answer (score 12):

## EDIT: I just edited this code because I had some issues with the old one. If you're using the old version please update.

This thread is a bit old but I just re-wrote some of the code here to do the same thing but on a more elegant way, using an extension method.

I'm using this on ASP.net Webforms, and I like to have the ashx files on a folder and being able to call them either using routing or a normal request.

So I pretty much grabbed shellscape's code and made an extension method that does the trick. At the end I felt that I should also support passing the IHttpHandler object instead of its Url, so I wrote and overload of the MapHttpHandlerRoute method for that.

```
namespace System.Web.Routing
{
 public class HttpHandlerRoute<T> : IRouteHandler where T: IHttpHandler
 {
  private String _virtualPath = null;

  public HttpHandlerRoute(String virtualPath)
  {
   _virtualPath = virtualPath;
  }

  public HttpHandlerRoute() { }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
   return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  }
 }

 public class HttpHandlerRoute : IRouteHandler
 {
  private String _virtualPath = null;

  public HttpHandlerRoute(String virtualPath)
  {
   _virtualPath = virtualPath;
  }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_virtualPath))
   {
    return (IHttpHandler)System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler));
   }
   else
   {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("HttpHandlerRoute threw an error because the virtual path to the HttpHandler is null or empty.");
   }
  }
 }

 public static class RoutingExtension
 {
  public static void MapHttpHandlerRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string routeName, string routeUrl, string physicalFile, RouteValueDictionary defaults = null, RouteValueDictionary constraints = null)
  {
   var route = new Route(routeUrl, defaults, constraints, new HttpHandlerRoute(physicalFile));
   routes.Add(routeName, route);
  }

  public static void MapHttpHandlerRoute<T>(this RouteCollection routes, string routeName, string routeUrl, RouteValueDictionary defaults = null, RouteValueDictionary constraints = null) where T : IHttpHandler
  {
   var route = new Route(routeUrl, defaults, constraints, new HttpHandlerRoute<T>());
   routes.Add(routeName, route);
  }
 }
}
```

I'm putting it inside the same namespace of all the native routing objects so it will be automatically available.

So to use this you just have to call:

```
// using the handler url
routes.MapHttpHandlerRoute("DoSomething", "Handlers/DoSomething", "~/DoSomething.ashx");
```

Or

```
// using the type of the handler
routes.MapHttpHandlerRoute<MyHttpHanler>("DoSomething", "Handlers/DoSomething");
```

Enjoy,
Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm using your methods they look clean and work great for me.

Comment: Hi mate, Thanks for the feedback.
I just updated this code due a problem caching the request. Please use this new version.
If you want to keep track have a look at my blog: http://www.instanceofanobject.com
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, I noticed that, too.  Perhaps there is a built-in ASP.NET way to do this, but the trick for me was to create a new class derived from IRouteHandler:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class GenericHandlerRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        private string _virtualPath;
        private Type _handlerType;
        private static object s_lock = new object();

        public GenericHandlerRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
        {
            _virtualPath = virtualPath;
        }

        #region IRouteHandler Members

        public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            ResolveHandler();

            IHttpHandler handler = (IHttpHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(_handlerType);
            return handler;
        }

        #endregion

        private void ResolveHandler()
        {
            if (_handlerType != null)
                return;

            lock (s_lock)
            {
                // determine physical path of ashx
                string path = _virtualPath.Replace("~/", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Generic handler " + _virtualPath + " could not be found.");

                // parse the class name out of the .ashx file
                // unescaped reg-ex: (?<=Class=")[a-zA-Z\.]*
                string className;
                Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=Class=\")[a-zA-Z\\.]*");
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    Match match = regex.Match(str);
                    if (match == null)
                        throw new InvalidDataException("Could not determine class name for generic handler " + _virtualPath);

                    className = match.Value;
                }

                // get the class type from the name
                Assembly[] asms = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
                foreach (Assembly asm in asms)
                {
                    _handlerType = asm.GetType(className);
                    if (_handlerType != null)
                        break;
                }

                if (_handlerType == null)
                    throw new InvalidDataException("Could not find type " + className + " in any loaded assemblies.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To create a route for an .ashx:

```
IRouteHandler routeHandler = new GenericHandlerRouteHandler("~/somehandler.ashx");
Route route = new Route("myroute", null, null, null, routeHandler);
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

The code above may need to be enhanced to work with your route arguments, but it's starting point.  Comments welcome.

Answer (score 5):

All of these answers are very good.  I love the simplicity of Mr. Meacham's `GenericHandlerRouteHandler<T>` class.  It is a great idea to eliminate an unnecessary reference to a virtual path if you know the specific `HttpHandler` class.  The `GenericHandlerRoute<T>` class is not needed, however.  The existing `Route` class which derives from `RouteBase` already handles all of the complexity of route matching, parameters, etc., so we can just use it along with `GenericHandlerRouteHandler<T>`.

Below is a combined version with a real-life usage example that includes route parameters.

First are the route handlers.  There are two included, here -- both with the same class name, but one that is generic and uses type information to create an instance of the specific `HttpHandler` as in Mr. Meacham's usage, and one that uses a virtual path and `BuildManager` to create an instance of the appropriate `HttpHandler` as in shellscape's usage.  The good news is that .NET allows both to live side by side just fine, so we can just use whichever we want and can switch between them as we wish.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class HttpHandlerRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler where T : IHttpHandler, new() {

  public HttpHandlerRouteHandler() { }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
    return new T();
  }
}

public class HttpHandlerRouteHandler : IRouteHandler {

  private string _VirtualPath;

  public HttpHandlerRouteHandler(string virtualPath) {
    this._VirtualPath = virtualPath;
  }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
    return (IHttpHandler) BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(this._VirtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler));
  }

}
```

Let's assume that we created an `HttpHandler` that streams documents to users from a resource outside our virtual folder, maybe even from a database, and that we want to fool the user's browser into believing that we are directly serving a specific file rather than simply providing a download (i.e., allow the browser's plug-ins to handle the file rather than forcing the user to save the file).  The `HttpHandler` may expect a document id with which to locate the document to provide, and may expect a file name to provide to the browser -- one that may differ from the file name used on the server.

The following shows the registration of the route used to accomplish this with a `DocumentHandler` `HttpHandler`:

```
routes.Add("Document", new Route("document/{documentId}/{*fileName}", new HttpHandlerRouteHandler<DocumentHandler>()));
```

I used `{*fileName}` rather than just `{fileName}` to allow the `fileName` parameter to act as an optional catch-all parameter.

To create a URL for a file served by this `HttpHandler`, we can add the following static method to a class where such a method would be appropriate, such as in the `HttpHandler` class, itself:

```
public static string GetFileUrl(int documentId, string fileName) {
  string mimeType = null;
  try { mimeType = MimeMap.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(fileName)); }
  catch { }
  RouteValueDictionary documentRouteParameters = new RouteValueDictionary {   { "documentId", documentId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }
                                                                            , { "fileName",   DocumentHandler.IsPassThruMimeType(mimeType) ? fileName : string.Empty } };
  return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "Document", documentRouteParameters).VirtualPath;
}
```

I omitted the definitions of `MimeMap` and and `IsPassThruMimeType` to keep this example simple.  But these are intended to determine whether or not specific file types should provide their file names directly in the URL, or rather in a `Content-Disposition` HTTP header.  Some file extensions could be blocked by IIS or URL Scan, or could cause code to execute that might cause problems for users -- especially if the source of the file is another user who is malicious.  You could replace this logic with some other filtering logic, or omit such logic entirely if you are not exposed to this type of risk.

Since in this particular example the file name may be omitted from the URL, then, obviously, we must retrieve the file name from somewhere.  In this particular example, the file name can be retrieved by performing a look-up using document id, and including a file name in the URL is intended solely to improve the user's experience.  So, the `DocumentHandler` `HttpHandler` can determine if a file name was provided in the URL, and if it was not, then it can simply add a `Content-Disposition` HTTP header to the response.

**Staying on topic**, the important part of the above code block is the usage of `RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath()` and the routing parameters to generate a URL from the `Route` object that we created during the route registration process.

Here's a watered-down version of the `DocumentHandler` `HttpHandler` class (much omitted for the sake of clarity).  You can see that this class uses route parameters to retrieve the document id and the file name when it can; otherwise, it will attempt to retrieve the document id from a query string parameter (i.e., assuming that routing was not used).

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

  try {

    context.Response.Clear();

    // Get the requested document ID from routing data, if routed.  Otherwise, use the query string.
    bool    isRouted    = false;
    int?    documentId  = null;
    string  fileName    = null;
    RequestContext requestContext = context.Request.RequestContext;
    if (requestContext != null && requestContext.RouteData != null) {
      documentId  = Utility.ParseInt32(requestContext.RouteData.Values["documentId"] as string);
      fileName    = Utility.Trim(requestContext.RouteData.Values["fileName"] as string);
      isRouted    = documentId.HasValue;
    }

    // Try the query string if no documentId obtained from route parameters.
    if (!isRouted) {
      documentId  = Utility.ParseInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
      fileName    = null;
    }
    if (!documentId.HasValue) { // Bad request
      // Response logic for bad request omitted for sake of simplicity
      return;
    }

    DocumentDetails documentInfo = ... // Details of loading this information omitted

    if (context.Response.IsClientConnected) {

      string fileExtension = string.Empty;
      try { fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName ?? documentInfo.FileName); } // Use file name provided in URL, if provided, to get the extension.
      catch { }

      // Transmit the file to the client.
      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(documentInfo.StoragePath);
      using (FileStream fileStream = file.OpenRead()) {

        // If the file size exceeds the threshold specified in the system settings, then we will send the file to the client in chunks.
        bool mustChunk = fileStream.Length > Math.Max(SystemSettings.Default.MaxBufferedDownloadSize * 1024, DocumentHandler.SecondaryBufferSize);

        // WARNING! Do not ever set the following property to false!
        //          Doing so causes each chunk sent by IIS to be of the same size,
        //          even if a chunk you are writing, such as the final chunk, may
        //          be shorter than the rest, causing extra bytes to be written to
        //          the stream.
        context.Response.BufferOutput   = true;

        context.Response.ContentType = MimeMap.GetMimeType(fileExtension);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        if (   !isRouted
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileExtension)) {  // If routed and a file name was provided in the route, then the URL will appear to point directly to a file, and no file name header is needed; otherwise, add the header.
          context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentInfo.FileName)));
        }

        int     bufferSize      = DocumentHandler.SecondaryBufferSize;
        byte[]  buffer          = new byte[bufferSize];
        int     bytesRead       = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0 && context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
          context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          if (mustChunk) {
            context.Response.Flush();
          }
        }
      }

    }

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // Error handling omitted from this example.
  }
}
```

This example uses some additional custom classes, such as a `Utility` class to simplify some trivial tasks.  But hopefully you can weed through that.  The only really important part in this class with regard to the current topic, of course, is the retrieval of the route parameters from `context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData`.  But I've seen several posts elsewhere asking how to stream large files using an `HttpHandler` without chewing up server memory, so it seemed like a good idea to combine examples.