# Call ashx handler file in asp.net 4.0 Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes

How to call handler captcha.ashx file routing asp.net 4.0 without MVC?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359816/can-asp-net-routing-be-used-to-create-clean-urls-for-ashx-ihttphander-handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `typeof(IHttpHandler)` instead of `typeof(Page) as IHttpHandler`