# Prevent direct access to image files on IIS Server?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

I have a folder named Pictures under my domain  (mydomain.com/pictures). I use these pictures on certain pages like with tags like:

```
<img src="pictures/image.jpg" alt="img" />
```

Now can I somehow prevent these pictures from being reached directly? I dont want to be able to access the picture by typing "mydomain.com/pictures/image.jpg" in the addressbar. I only want them accessed when called from server tags like the one above.

I am using IIS server and PHP scripting language.I have read [ASP Hack](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.ca/2008/02/sometimes-we-as-programmers-we-might.html)

Comment: Perhaps read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access) and translate the htaccess rules to IIS using [this](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)

Comment: Yes I did, most of them are using apache server using htaccess, but as I have mentioned I am on IIS it won't help.

Comment: Adjust your title to reflect it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect against direct access to images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990337/how-to-protect-against-direct-access-to-images)

Comment: @RST I have changed question title.You can tags btw

Comment: I know, but it makes it more obvious what you are looking for when people have a list of topics on their screen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313670/prevent-direct-access-to-files-on-iis-server

Comment: @MaxZuber different platforms.

Comment: @user1885057 It doesn't matter, it's just a clue.

Comment: @MaxZuber the link share is irrelevant. i want to images from direct url.